# Using CSS class prefixes as namespaces

Tags: css, less

I was thinking of creating a LESS stylesheet where I'd have a given prefix which would work as a namespace.

I've got this (working) code so far:

```
.FormAdd { // common prefix to all of its children
  &-buttons { // the real class in HTML is .FormAdd-buttons
    display: block;
    ...
  }

  &-results { // the real class in HTML is .FormAdd-results
    display: inline;
    ...
  }
}
```

**BUT** I would rather have this code (just seems prettier to me):

```
.FormAdd {
  buttons { 
    display: block;
    ...
  }

  results {
    display: inline;
    ...
  }
}
```

Is this somehow possible to achieve (preferably in LESS) without creating my own CSS preprocessor?

Comment: Without the `&`, the nested selectors would be considered as selecting child elements and not same element. So, no it is not possible. People may come up with some very intelligent hack but it would look even uglier than the first snippet.

Comment: Mmm, maybe you need to create your own preprocessor, or use that way to work.

Comment: The hacks are probably what I'm looking for :-). But thanks, you're right that's likely not possible to achieve.